# How to know what index is set on the table with command line in informix?

Tags: informix

I'm using the Informix DB. I want to detect what index the table has using command line. I used

```
dbschema -d dbName -t  tableName | grep index
```

to detect the index. What's my problem is that the dbschema output format is not specified (hard to automatically parse it) so I don't think it is reliable. Is there any better way to automatically detect the index instead of read by human?

Answer (score 1):

I think understand your problem.

The dbaccess break lines at the middle of the statement and the table name goes to line bellow...
Something like this (dbschema output)

```
create unique index "informix".ix1c_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix"
    .h_dbases_2012_06 (seq,site_name) using btree  filtering
```

I consider two solutions 100% functional...

## First suggestion

Parse the dbschema with awk to join the lines until found a semicolon.
This will give to you long lines... 
Then you can work little more with awk/sed to get only the index and table name... not so hard.
But this probably will become a shell script.

```
$ dbschema -d dba  -t h_dbases_2012_06| awk '{printf $0} /;/{print ""}' | egrep "create.index"
create index "informix".ix10_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,pagwrites) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix11_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,total_sorts) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix12_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,isreads) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix13_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,iswrites) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix14_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,iscommits) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix15_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,net_write_mb) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix16_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,horini) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix1_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (seq) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix1b_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (seq,hostname) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix2_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,username) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix3_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,cpu_time) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix4_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,programa) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix5_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,tarefa) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix6_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,hostname) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix7_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,maxlog_kb) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix8_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,net_read_mb) using btree ;
create index "informix".ix9_h_dbases_2012_06 on "informix".h_dbases_2012_06     (datini,pagereads) using btree ;
```

## Second suggestion

Query the database.
For this , they should be a script and your user should have access to database with dbaccess

```
$ cat x.sh
dbaccess -e - <<EOF
database $1 ;
select t.tabname[1,20] as table, i.idxname[1,20] as idx
from systables t , sysindices i
where t.tabid = i.tabid
  and t.tabname matches lower("$2*")
  and t.tabid > 99
order by 1,2
;
EOF

$ sh x.sh dba h_dbases_2014_04
database dba ;
Database selected.


select t.tabname[1,20] as table, i.idxname[1,20] as idx
from systables t , sysindices i
where t.tabid = i.tabid
  and t.tabname matches lower("h_dbases_2014_04*")
  and t.tabid > 99
order by 1,2
;

table                idx

h_dbases_2014_04     ix10_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix11_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix12_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix13_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix14_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix15_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix16_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix1_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix1b_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix1c_h_dbases_2014_0
h_dbases_2014_04     ix2_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix3_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix4_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix5_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix6_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix7_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix8_h_dbases_2014_04
h_dbases_2014_04     ix9_h_dbases_2014_04

18 row(s) retrieved.




Database closed.
```

Comment: Great answer. I can add that I have made specialized tool to dump Informix schema information in easy to compare format: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621-dump-informix-schema-to-text/?in=user-186902  It requires Python or Jython, but uses SQL schema queries similar to 2nd suggestion.